# Correct display Qt Gui on Linux with 8-bits color. Dots at the dialog

Tags: linux, user-interface, colors, qt4.8, 8-bit

**Update:**
Now I know, that the reason is 8-bit color in the system. But I still have no decision.

The first dialog created with Xlib and the second one is the Qt dialog. Both dialogs are very simple.

[image: X11/Xlib vs Qt]

The code for Qt Project is here [Window Flags Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html).

Comment: How could we know, without seeing your code?

Comment: The code for Qt is here [Window Flags Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html). I think the problem is not in the code. Probably something wrong with libraries...

Comment: I hope, that somebody have seen it before.

Comment: Code-wise I've seen a similar issue when changing the geometry of a widget and not updating it properly. In other cases on low spec-ed machines it was pure rendering issue that is performance of the underlying hardware in combination with poorly optimized GPU drivers.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to start it at another machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QApplication::setGraphicsSystem("native");